# Ho to get all fields from firebase except one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have user profile `$profileId` in firebase with fields

```
 email
 name
 ratings
 type
 uid
```

I want to get access for all public users to read profile data except `email`. I tried this

```
"$profileId": {
        ".indexOn": ".value",
        ".read": true,
        "email": {
          ".read": "auth.uid == $profileId"
        }
      }
```

But all fields are public in this case. How I can hide `email` field without changing db structure?

Thanks

Comment: Once a node is accessible (read or write) to a user, you cannot take that permission away on a lower level. You cannot use security rules to filter (or selectively expose) data. This has been covered *a lot* here under its moniker ["rules are not filters"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters). I'll mark as a duplicate as one of those.